# Mapping unique/timestamp combination to email/timestamp combination

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing

I have two dataframes. One df contains an email and a timestamp of when someone opened an email. The other df contains a unique id and a timestamp of when someone clicked on the email. However, this data is captured in two different servers and their timestamps are off by a varied amount i.e (some click timestamps are possibly before the open timestamp and some possibly after). I want to either 1) run tests to see if these two datasets are off by some constant and calculate the match rates for each test or 2) run statistical tests that calculate the probability that a unique id/timestamp combination belong to an email/timestamp combination and then the highest probability would create a match. The problem is that I have more click/timestamp observations than email/timestamp observations. Also, two different email addresses cannot have the same unique id but the same email address can have multiple timestamps. What methods do you advise?

Comment: What is the circumstance that you have both of these logs but not a canonical mapping from ids to emails? If your organization is sending the emails (and therefore creating the ids), then you should just keep track of the mapping ahead of time. If you're not sending them and didn't ever know their emails... then be careful not to violate your users' expectations of privacy.

Comment: This is third party data. The open data comes from one data vendor and the click data comes from another third party vendor.

Comment: Yeah, still having difficulty imagining a scenario where this is both necessary and ethical.

Comment: @StumpyJoePete I can imagine various scenarios, for instance a non-profit may have their website hosted at entity X and send some newsletter or invitation via entity Y's mailing lists. Could also be something as simple as a petition which gets distributed via various means.

Comment: @Nemo If the non-profit is constructing the newletter and website, they can arrange to have unique ids ahead of time (which makes the matching trivial). Doing it this way instead is hacky and error prone. If, on the other hand, they're just buying data about other people, then... I'm not really interested in solving their problem.